# How to return a set as function result

Tags: turbo-pascal

### What I have

In TurboPascal I have defined an enumerated type `TState` and a set `TStateS` of this type.

```
type
  TState = (CS_Type1, CS_Type2, CS_Type3, CS_Type4 );
  TStateS = set of TState;
```

Also I have a function doing some calculation that should return a set

```
function Calc: TStateS;
begin
  { do calculate here and return }
  Calc := CS_Type1 + CS_Type2;
end;
```

### My problem

The TurboPascal compiler complains with Error 34 "Invalid result type of function". The turbo pascal manual states that ordinal types are ok but does not mention sets.

### My Question

Is there any other method of returning a set as a function result?

Comment: Use a reference parameter instead: `procedure Calc( var return: TStateS );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"+" operates on sets and creates a union of the two, but CS_Type1 and CS_Type2 are not sets, but as you stated, enumerated types. To create and return a set of those two enums, you can use a *set literal*:

```
  Calc := [CS_Type1 , CS_Type2];
```

That allows your code to compile and work on Free Pascal. Not sure about Turbo Pascal, but the principle is the same, create a *set* of the enumerated types CS_Type1 and CS_Type2 and return that.